# Update column when other column hasn't changed for an hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 database where I have some tables. Can we update a `columnA` with some value after checking that `columnB` has not been updated in the last hour?

```
UPDATE tableA
SET columnA = columnA + someaddition
WHERE (columnC = 1)
AND (columnB = 'here I need the condition to check whether columnD has not been updated within past one hour')
```

In short, I have to update `ColumnA` with a condition in `columnC` and `columnB`, and update `columnA` only for those rows in which `columnD` has not been updated within the last hour.

Comment: Do you have an update date column in your table?  The most straightforward way to do this is to have a column such as "ColumnDUpdateDate" and keep it updated as appropriate.  Your query then becomes simple.

Comment: How do you know if the column has been updated in the last hour?, do you have a column with `LastUpdated` or something similar?. Also, I think that you are mixing `ColumnB` and `ColumnD` on your question, you got me confused

Comment: s, i have a date update column its gets updated when ever any column is updated in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, if you store update time of column B.

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET columnA = columnA + someaddition
WHERE (columnC = 1) 
AND (columnB_update>DATEADD(minute, -60, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: This is good, but one correction, i asked to check coulumnB is not updated within last one hour. This works good if we change the query like this AND (columnB_update      <       DATEADD(minute, -60, GETDATE()))